# How can i get all data using (graphql query + relay) in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, relayjs

I have to try to get all data from my PostgreSQL database using graphql query + relay.

i have implement one query in following file:

```
const PropertyP = nextQuery<propertyQuery, { propertyId: string }>(ctx => ({
  query: graphql`
    query propertyQuery($propertyId: ID!) {
      property: node(id: $propertyId) {
        ...Property_property
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    propertyId: ctx.query.propertyId || NULL_PROPERTY_ID,
  },
  // cacheStrategy: 'cache-first',
}))(PropertyPage);
```

and one relay graphql file and this file located at
`web/pages/__generated__/propertyQuery.graphql.js`

this file content is following:

```
const node/*: ConcreteRequest*/ = (function(){
var v0 = [
  {
    "kind": "LocalArgument",
    "name": "propertyId",
    "type": "ID!",
    "defaultValue": null
  }
],
v1 = [
  {
    "kind": "Variable",
    "name": "id",
    "variableName": "propertyId",
    "type": "ID!"
  }
];
return {
  "kind": "Request",
  "operationKind": "query",
  "name": "propertyQuery",
  "id": null,
  "text": "query propertyQuery(\n  $propertyId: ID!\n) {\n  property: node(id: $propertyId) {\n    __typename\n    ...Property_property\n    id\n  }\n}\n\nfragment Property_property on Property {\n  id\n  livingSurface\n  landSurface\n  numberOfRooms\n  numberOfParkings\n}\n",
  "metadata": {},
  "fragment": {
    "kind": "Fragment",
    "name": "propertyQuery",
    "type": "Query",
    "metadata": null,
    "argumentDefinitions": v0,
    "selections": [
      {
        "kind": "LinkedField",
        "alias": "property",
        "name": "node",
        "storageKey": null,
        "args": v1,
        "concreteType": null,
        "plural": false,
        "selections": [
          {
            "kind": "FragmentSpread",
            "name": "Property_property",
            "args": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "operation": {
    "kind": "Operation",
    "name": "propertyQuery",
    "argumentDefinitions": v0,
    "selections": [
      {
        "kind": "LinkedField",
        "alias": "property",
        "name": "node",
        "storageKey": null,
        "args": v1,
        "concreteType": null,
        "plural": false,

      }
    ]
  }
};
})();
// prettier-ignore
(node/*: any*/).hash = '568e84b911100cf5010ec35e0b6ff480';
module.exports = node;
```

this file hold's the query and operation in relay and graphql.

I have tried to get all the data from particular `propertyId` in my properties table. but, it only returns the properties id.

so, how can I get all data in `React.Component` file